# How to avoid to implement method with useless parameters to satisfy interface conditions?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a IFoo interface with a Bar method, taking a string argument. This interface got an implementation that returns a constant value, without using the argument at all. The other uses the parameters.

How can I avoid this useless parameter ?
Here is a dummy implementation

```
  public interface IFoo
    {
        string Bar(string parameter);
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public string Bar(string parameter)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}Fooooooo", parameter);
        }
    }

    public class ConstantFoo : IFoo
    {
        public string Bar(string parameter)
        {
            return "Baaaaaaar";
        }
    }

    public class Caller
    {
        private readonly IFoo _foo;
        private readonly IFoo _constFoo;
        public Caller()
        {
            _foo = new Foo();
            _constFoo = new ConstantFoo();
        }
        public void DummyUsage()
        {
            string arg = "Wololo";
            Console.WriteLine(_foo.Bar(arg));
            Console.WriteLine(_constFoo.Bar(arg));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Interface defining contract ..You are not forced to use this parameter.
Another case is for example events .. 
Imagine microsoft provide you some events. Usually eventhandler method has 2 arguments 
`void  MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` 
Once event is is fired this hndler is called and 2 arguments are usable in method scope. You can use them but there is not force to force you use them.

The same you can apply to interface (3rd party) in case you are producer of interface, maybe you can think about how to change design of your application.

Comment: Interface is a contract. When you have instance of `IFoo`, you know only it has `Bar(string)` and you don't know if parameter is useless or not, you have to pass it. It's ok if implementation doesn't uses it, but it still has to follow a contract and define this parameter as method signature. You can give it some fancy name, e.g. `notUsed` and even give optional default value (or use overload), then if you have `ConstantFoo` instance you can call `Bar()` without parameter

Comment: Example of Sinatr's comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9rrkD

Comment: @Fildor I think in this case optional arguments are not good idea

Comment: @PeterM. I just compiled an example of what Sinatr proposed for OP to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example counts with one fact.. You as producer of class know about implementation detail that you Exactly know what type of instance is `IFoo`

```cs
public class Caller
    {
        private readonly IFoo _foo;
        private readonly IFoo _constFoo;
        public Caller()
        {
            _foo = new Foo();   // => here is exact instance type
            _constFoo = new ConstantFoo(); // => here is exact instance type
        }
        public void DummyUsage()
        {
            string arg = "Wololo";
            Console.WriteLine(_foo.Bar(arg)); // -> here you know that you need parameterarg
            Console.WriteLine(_constFoo.Bar(arg)); // -> here you know that you do not need parameter arg

        }
```

Now think about this:

```
public class Caller
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IFoo> _fooServices;

        public Caller(IEnumerable<IFoo> fooServices)
        {
            _fooServices = fooServices;
        }
        public void DummyUsage()
        {
            string arg = "Wololo";

           foreach(IFoo fooService in _fooServices)
          {
               Console.WriteLine(fooService.Bar(arg)); //==> you do not know what type of foo it is if it require internally argument or not .. But you have to pass it to satisfy contract defined by IFoo interface
          }

        }
```

---

Now another

Imagine you have 2 interfaces:

```cs
interface IFoo 
{
    void Bar();
}

interface IParametrizedFoo
{
    void Bar(string parameter);
}
```

then you can have implementation

```cs
public class Foo : IParametrizedFoo
    {
        public string Bar(string parameter)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}Fooooooo", parameter);
        }
    }

    public class ConstantFoo : IFoo, IParametrizedFoo
    {
        public string Bar()
        {
            return "Baaaaaaar";
        }

      string  IParametrizedFoo.Bar(string parameter)
{
Bar();
}
    }
```

then usage

```cs
public class Caller
    {
        private readonly IParametrizedFoo _parametrizedFoo;
        private readonly IFoo _foo;
        public Caller(IParametrizedFoo parametrizedFoo, IFoo foo)
        {
            _parametrizedFoo= parametrizedFoo;
            _foo= foo;
        }
        public void DummyUsage()
        {
            string arg = "Wololo";
            Console.WriteLine(parametrizedFoo.Bar(arg));
            Console.WriteLine(_foo.Bar());

        }
```

**But still i do not think is the best design**

Answer (score 1):

The signature of a function or property that a class implements always needs to be identical to the respective interface.
If you have control over the interface yourself, can can change the signature in both the interface and the implementing class.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar()
    {
        return "Fooooooo";
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want, it might suggest that your inheritance model is not very well defined.

Comment: where you lost `parameter` .. how is defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare an additional method Bar() without any parameter in the interface IFoo

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar(string parameter);

    string Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar(string parameter)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}Fooooooo", parameter);
    }

    public string Bar()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class ConstantFoo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar(string parameter)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public string Bar()
    {
        return "Baaaaaaar";
    }
}

public class Caller
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    private readonly IFoo _constFoo;
    public Caller()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        _constFoo = new ConstantFoo();
    }
    public void DummyUsage()
    {
        string arg = "Wololo";
        Console.WriteLine(_foo.Bar(arg));
        Console.WriteLine(_constFoo.Bar());

    }
}
```